# string.Split ignores Null values between delimiters

Tags: c#, string, null, split

I'm trying to convert some data into sql statements with the use  of Streamreader and Streamwriter.

My problem is, when i split lines which in which between 2 delimiters is nothing, not even a space, they get ignored and i get a IndexOutOfRange error

because my temparray only goes till temparray[3] , but it should go to like temparray[6] ..

How can i split and use Null values or replace those null values with a simple char, so that i dont get an IndexOutOfRange error when i want to create my sql statements ?

```
foreach (string a in values)
{
    int temp = 1;
    String[] temparray = a.Split(';');
    streamWriter.WriteLine("Insert into table Firma values({0},'{1}','{2}')", temp, temparray[1], temparray[4]);
    temp++;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of string which causes a problem?

Comment: **DON'T BUILD SQL STATEMENTS THIS WAY!** It's vulnerable to injection attacks. Code like this is practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: `"A;;;C".Split(';').Length` yields `4`.

Comment: @user3107760 Please include some wording in your comment to say that the string that you have posted is an example input, not a nonsensical comment in German :-)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this is asking for trouble ([SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)). You should *at the very least* escape the values parsed from the string.

And you seem to be mistaken, as String.Split does exactly what you want *by default*: `"x;y;;z".Split(';')` returns a four-element array `{"x", "y", "", "z"}`. You can achieve the described behavior by using `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`: `"x;y;;z".Split(new[] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` returns a *three*-element array `{"x", "y", "z"}`. Which is what you do not want, as you say.

Either way, `"Überarbeitung der SAV Seite;b.i.b.;;;;PB;".Split(';')` returns a seven-element array here for me, so check your inputs and implementation…

Comment: I didnt even know what an SQL injection is ok.. and i think it won't be a problem on my small Site, it's only to show some Informations, nothing more.
By default test1;;;;test2 it only shows test1 and test2 for me.

Comment: Ok i will try it with RemoveEmptyEntries.None   , how do i do line breaks here ??

Answer (score 1):

If you print out your string, I'm pretty sure it will not be what you expect it to be.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var result = "Überarbeitung der SAV Seite;b.i.b.;;;;PB;".Split(';');

  foreach (var part in result)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(" --> " + part);
  }

  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This works great. It will not ignore the empty values. It will print

```
 --> Überarbeitung der SAV Seite
 --> b.i.b.
 -->
 -->
 -->
 --> PB
 -->
```

including the empty values.

Greetings to bib Paderborn :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server, you can return empty strings instead of null by using the ISNULL operator in your query.

For example:

```
SELECT ISNULL(PR_Arbeitstitel, '') FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you iterate over your temparray to build up a string of param values.

This is by no means perfect, but should point you in the direction

```
    foreach (string a in values)
    {
        int temp = 1;
        String[] temparray = a.Split(';');

        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var s in temparray)
            stringBuilder.Append("'" + s + "',");

        var insertStatement = string.Format("Insert into table Firma values({0}, {1})", temp, stringBuilder.ToString().TrimEnd(','));

        temp++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you have 2 delimiters in a row with nothing inbetween them? Do you not control the input?

In that case you could control it by inserting a so-called sentinel value, such as "IGNOREMEPLEASE":

```
String[] temparray = a.Replace(";;", ";IGNOREMEPLEASE;").Split(';');
```

Then the rest of your code knows that `IGNOREMEPLEASE` means there was an empty line, and it should be ignored.

That being said, be very careful about what you send to a database, and scrub incoming data that you use to build SQL statements with, to get rid of anything dangerous.

Comment: The input is from an excel Table, not mine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your issue occurring.  The following outputs a string.Empty for string[2] and has all 5 elements

```
        string[] str = "0,1,,3,4".Split(new char[] { ',' });
        foreach (string s in str)
        {
            Debug.Print(s);
        }
```

output

```
0
1

3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce with your example of string `"Überarbeitung der SAV Seite;b.i.b.;;;;PB;"` but everything was fine. I've got 7 items in array.
You can try to use

```
string s = "Überarbeitung der SAV Seite;b.i.b.;;;;PB;";
var result = s.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

To be sure that `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` is not enabled.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps use the `??` operator:

```
streamWriter.WriteLine(
    "Insert into table Firma values({0},'{1}','{2}')",
    temp,
    temparray[1] ?? 'x',
    temparray[4] ?? 'x');
```

This still is only safe, though, if you know *for sure* that your input has at least 5 tokens after splitting. If you can't guarantee this you'll need to wrap it in a conditional:

```
if (temparray.Length < 5)
{
    // handle invalid input
}
```